# How important is "mm pitch" for a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, components, repair

I want to repair my boiler, so I found [this](http://www.rojtberg.net/645/repairing-philips-hd4685-kettle/) howto.

He writes I need a `MKP X2, 26.5 x 10 x 19 mm, 0.47 µF 275 V/AC ±10%, 22.5 mm pitch`.

The closet one I can find in my country is [this one](http://www.conradelektronik.dk/?websale8=conrad-dk&shopid=conrad-dk&pi=450252) that doesn't mention `22.5 mm pitch`.

**Question**

What is `mm pitch` and is it important for my usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pitch` is the spacing between component pins or, like with your capacitor, the spacing between the leads. It doesn't really affect the electrical characteristics of the part and are solely for mechanical fit.

Answer (score 3):

It's the distance between the leads in millimeters. It's important if you want it to fit in the same space.

Answer (score 2):

`pitch` [in mm] is the distance between the leads (pins) of the capacitor.  This pitch dimension normally mates with the corresponding distance between the holes on the circuit board.  However, this is not that important in the O.P.'s case, because the capacitor is mounted in a bent fashion.  The replacement capacitor, which the O.P. had found is smaller and has smaller pitch.  But the leads can be bent out to accommodate wider pitch.

Having said that, repair questions are off-topic on EE.SE

Answer (score 1):

"Pitch" refers to how far apart the leads are. For through-hole discretes it's not vitally important since the leads will have some give on most through-hole packages, but the more you have to bend them off pitch the worse the fit will be.